# Clearing the console in Kotlin

Tags: java, jvm, kotlin

When using the usual `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear")` as you would in Java, nothing happens. However, if instead use `touch test.txt` a text file is indeed created. Is there a reason for this, and if so, are there any alternatives?

Both work in Java in the same environment.

EDIT: Missed brackets

Comment: Have you checked if an exception is thrown?  try/catch around `exec`

Comment: Just tried, not being thrown

Comment: In most environments, `clear` is a shell macro or alias for `echo <some esc sequence>` which can *not* get executed via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(…)` as `exec` only works for true executable binaries on the path. But, as said, that’s system dependent. However, on all systems, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(…)` redirects the output to a pipe, so commands working by sending control characters to the standard output have no effect on the actual console. In other words, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear")` is very unlikely to work.

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `print("\u001b[H\u001b[2J")`, using an escape sequence, at least on Linux.